# Speeding up Encryption

Tags: c#, networking, encryption, network-programming

So this is how I am doing encryption right now:

```
public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] Data, string Password, string Salt)
        {
            char[] converter = Salt.ToCharArray();
            byte[] salt = new byte[converter.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < converter.Length; i++)
            {
                salt[i] = (byte)converter[i];
            }

            PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = new PasswordDeriveBytes(Password, salt);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            Aes aes = new AesManaged();
            aes.Key = pdb.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
            aes.IV = pdb.GetBytes(aes.BlockSize / 8);
            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            cs.Write(Data, 0, Data.Length); 
            cs.Close();

            return ms.ToArray();
        }
```

I am using this algorithm on data streaming over a network. The problem is it is a bit slow for what I am trying to do. So I was wondering if anyone has better way of doing it? I am no expert on encryption this method was pieced together from different sources. I am not entirely sure how it works.

I have clocked it at about 0.5-1.5ms and I need to get it down to about 0.1ms any ideas?

Comment: You want to skip the managed stuff then. Try the native ciphers instead.

Comment: @ rsaxvc Not a lot of data. the average packet size is about 20bytes. The measured times were on a packet of 6bytes.                                @ leppie What do you mean native ciphers? Googling it did not come up with much.

Comment: The one without managed in their name :) Try `AesCryptoServiceProvider` instead of `AesManaged`.

Comment: If you're measuring these times when encrypting only 6 bytes, it's clear that the encryption itself is not the thing taking so much time -- it's all that object initialization. You probably have to cache as many objects as you can to avoid having to recreate them.

Comment: @Gabe which means everything but the stream *and the IV* (or key if it is a single use session key)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that performance is the least of your problems here.

Is the salt re-used for each packet? If so, you're using a strong cypher in a weak fashion. You're starting each packet with the cypher in exactly the same state. This is a security flaw. Someone skilled in cryptography would be able to crack your encryption after only a couple thousand packets.

I'm assuming you're sending a stream of packets to the same receiver. In that case, your use of AES will be much stronger if you keep the Aes object around and re-use it. That will make your use of the cypher much, much stronger and speed things up greatly.

As to the performance question, most of your time is being spent initializing the cypher. If you don't re-initialize it every time, you'll speed up quite a lot.

Comment: You are right re-initializing it was the problem. Thanks for the security advice I will change that now.

Comment: Just tested it out and now I am getting 10microseconds. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Isn't that much slower than what you started with? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @owlstead: ms means milliseconds, so his speed was .5 - 1.5ms and now it is .01ms

Comment: @GregS ... D'oh! That was pretty slow though - didn't expect that.

Comment: @Axis Please take to heart the lesson about the security flaw. Using cryptography is not the end of security problems, it's just the beginning :) Schneier's Law http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schneier's_law is something to be taken very seriously.

Answer (score 0):

`aes.KeySize>>3` would be faster than `aes.KeySize / 8`.

Comment: You do realize `sizeof(char) != sizeof(byte)` ?

Comment: My fault, I forgot about unicode, I don't do .NET much. I guess if you need a byte array or ansi string to encrypt then you might look to passing that into the function, getting rid of the c# char to byte conversion would save a lot of time.

Comment: the problem is more in the PasswordDeriveBytes pdb to CryptoStream cs = new. The code that you are changing already executes in about 10 microseconds

Comment: @Motes: No difference, any decent compiler would optimize that.

Comment: @leppie: Funny how the OP creates all object instances  for each encrypt/decrypt (only the stream and IV should not be static) and the performance tip is about using the shift operator - a performance tip for machine language :)